# textview does not "fill_parent" in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to display an id next to a list item. Even though I set the id textview height to fill_parent it does not seem to have any effect. Here is my full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/bgColor"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DisplayID"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_marginRight="1px"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:background="#ead7a4"
    android:padding="12px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DisplayText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/DisplayID"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:background="#ead7a4"
    android:padding="12px"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DisplayTextPhonetic"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DisplayTextArabic" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/DisplayID"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:background="#ead7a4"
    android:padding="12px"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/DisplayTextTrans"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DisplayTextPhonetic" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/DisplayID"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:background="#ead7a4"
    android:padding="12px"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What effect do you think it should have?

Comment: I want to have an ID to the left and three textviews adjacent to it to the right. It is working now except for the ID textview background color.

Comment: can you include a screenshot of what is wrong with the background

Comment: also, you are setting some of your textviews layout_width to fill_parent, but then also arranging them in a relative way, using layout_toRightOf.  Those are conflicting statements.

Comment: The attribute android:layout_orientation doesn't belong to RelativeLayout, maybe you could try to remove it. Also, why you put android:visibility="gone" in the last two textview?

Comment: I solved the problem following a tutorial on Android blog, I posted the link in the answers. As for the visibility attribute I need to initially hide these views and then display based on user preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by following this tutorial:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

It is very useful for beginners in Android UI.